# Downloaded new skill and cannot push dev

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I created a new skill in the web-based interface.  Then I used the skills extension in vscode to download the new skill.  After downloading I have the interactionModel as an untracked file in the dev branch.  I committed that and some other files and tried to push it to get things synced up and it failed, saying to do a pull first.  I do the pull succesfully and then try the push again and get the same error.  What can I do to sync things?

EDIT:  I tried pushing from a shell and got "get: .ask\scripts\git-credential-helper: not found". So I couldn't log in to the amazon repo.  Could this be causing the problem above?  How do I get my credentials for the remote repo?  I assumed that would be set up automatically from the alexa-skill extension in vscode when I downloaded the skill.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my problem [here](https://github.com/alexa/ask-cli/issues/355#issuecomment-740251526)

The commands I used were ...

```
    git checkout dev
    git pull --rebase
    git merge master
    # fix any merge conflict if you have any
    git push --no-verify
```